# Multiprocessing gets locked with larger amount of inputs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking

I have difficulties in understanding the problem I am running into. Some background information: I am processing large numbers of files that are loaded, processed and saved. Although files are rather big and steps within multiprocessing time-consuming, it's very repetitive so according to some posts here, I wrote a way to run this in parallel using multiprocessing. It works perfectly for 2-4 files, but somehow it locks when I try to run 10-20 files. The interesting thing, though, is that apparently the problem is in the last estimation or pool.join, as all data except for one file are saved. To be honest, I don't even know how to pinpoint the problem. Does anyone have a suggestion what I could try to do or where the problem might be? Here is a MRE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import multiprocessing as mp
import math
import sys
import traceback

pool = None

class ProcessData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.multiprocessing_files()

    def function_to_execute(self, foo, bar):
        # some processing of files and saving to folder
        print("Process: {}; Running for file {}; folder: {}".format(mp.current_process().name, foo, bar))

    def multiprocessing_files(self):
        data_tuple = ("x1", "y1"), ("x2", "y2"), ("x3", "z3") # input is a filename and a folder

        pool = mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(int(math.floor(mp.cpu_count() / 2)))
        for foo, bar in data_tuple:
            pool.apply_async(func=self.func_wrapper_debug,  # self.N4BiasCorrection_multiprocessing
                             args=(foo, bar), callback=self.prompt)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()


    def prompt(self, result):
        if result:
            print('\nPreprocessing finished!')
            pool.terminate()

    def func_wrapper_debug(self, foo, bar):
        try:
            self.function_to_execute(foo, bar)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception("".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProcessData()
```